# Win32: How to prevent DateTimePicker from accepting 2-digit years?

Tags: datetime, winapi, y2k, common-controls, 2-digit-year

Microsoft's `DateTimePicker` common control shows **ShortDate**'s according to the configured Locale settings. The customer's computer is configured with a 2-digit year ShortDateFormat (`d/M/yy`), so the DateTimePicker shows 2-digit years:

[image]

When the user puts focus in the year block of the datetime picker, Microsoft points out the issue, and shows the full 4-digit year:

[image]

But then the user, wanting to enter `1929` as a year, types a 2-digit year:

[image]

And then when they tab out they're confused when Windows interprets their 2-digit years as being between `1930` and `2029`, and it is assumed to be 2029:

[image]

The customer has a global corporate policy in place which dictates that Windows regional settings be configured for 2-digit years.

So as a workaround i need to force every `DateTimePicker` control to use a custom date-format, using the handy [`DateTime_SetFormat` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-datetime_setformat):

```
DateTime_SetFormat(hwnd_DateOfEventPicker, "d/M/yyyy");
```

This helps, so that now the `DateTimePicker` now always shows a 4-digit year:

[image]

The problem is that the user can still type in an "*invalid*" 2-digit year:

[image]

Which Windows is still intpreting, according to the rules, as 2029:

[image]

i need the date-time picker to reject 2-digit years.

If this can't work, then i'm going to be forced to replace every DateTimePicker with 3 edit boxes:

<kbd>22</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>29</kbd>

Where i can color invalid numbers red, and point out the invalid data entry by the user.

How can i prevent the DateTimePicker from accept y2k bugs?

Comment: I wish all the questions here were as well thought out and organized as this one.

Comment: @Ben313 The downside of a thorough question is that nobody can answer them. With all the "outs", or cheats, cut off, it only leaves people knowledgeable about a pretty specific problem domain. Also, you should see the original edit - where i got to have a free rant; knowing full well that i would edit them out a minute later.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the DTS_APPCANPARSE window style, you can handle the WM_NOTIFY: DTN_USERSTRING message and parse the string yourself

Comment: What the...i **know** i edited your answer, adding quoted text from the MSDN documentation, and link. And i know i commented on your answer, explaining why it can't work in my case. And now the edits, and comment, are gone. And there's not even any indication that the answer was ever edited. Did SO crash and rollback?